# Craft 3 RC install on MAMP Issue

Tags: mamp

I just installed the Craft 3 RC on MAMP - the install process executed without error and I can see all of the Craft files in the directory I specified and the .env file was updated with database info. However, when I try to run setup it throws an error ( The requested URL /cr3.dev/admin was not found on this server. ). I then deleted the entire directory and ran the Composer install again, but same issue when I try to run the Craft install process.

The MAMP server is working fine - an existing Craft 2 install works perfectly and just to be sure I created a new test directory with a single index.html file and that worked as well.

I realize this is not much info, but hoping someone has some ideas to guide me along!

Comment: First of all, you should be careful using `.dev` URLs. Just as a side note... More importantly does your web server point to your `web` directory? Did you try `index.php?p=admin`? When you use just the normal frontend url do you receive an `invalidRouteException`?

Comment: Can you tell us what the directory structure of your currently working Craft 2 site looks like? You most likely need to create a virtual host for your craft 3 url that changes the document root to be web like Robin mentioned.

Comment: More context on using `.dev`: https://medium.engineering/use-a-dev-domain-not-anymore-95219778e6fd

Comment: Thanks all! I did try index.php etc but no luck there. I am not a server guy, so excuse my ignorance here, but do not understand how setting the document root to web would work. Currently, the document root is Applications/MAMP/htdocs, which contains a folder called cr3.test (I changed it from.dev, thanks), which then contains the Craft install.